# PyGTK + Glade: botão sem manipulador dispara clique em outro botão

Tags: python, gtk, gtk-python

Olá, pessoal! Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Python usando PyGTK+ 3.0 com Glade 3.22.2 (e Python 3.8.1). Tudo estava funcionando bem, mas, subitamente, meu programa começou a mostrar um comportamento estranho. Eu tenho dois métodos para manipular cliques em botões:`on_save_file()` e `on_open_file()`. Essas funções recebem um `Gtk.Entry` como parâmetro e abrem/salvam um arquivo (através de um FileDialog), além de setar o filename desse arquivo para o `Gtk.Entry` fornecido.

A parte estranha começa agora: subitamente, um botão que abriria um arquivo começou a *magicamente* disparar um clique em outros dois botões em outra janela (e que estão em outro arquivo `.glade`) e que salvam um arquivo. O resultado são três FileDialogs aparecendo como se, de fato, o usuário tivesse clicado nos três botões ao mesmo tempo.

Para fazer uns testes, eu removi os sinais do botão em questão, mas ele continua disparando o clique nos outros dois botões, mesmo que ele próprio não tenha nenhum manipulador e não faça mais nada.

Eu também tentei voltar alguns commits no passado, mas o erro persistiu (e eu tenho quase certeza que isso não acontecia antes, como também tenho quase certeza de não ter atualizado nada na minha máquina).

Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde esse problema pode estar?

Obrigado!

---

### Mais detalhes

Aqui estão meus três métodos que manipulam os sinais.

```py
# class blahblahblah: ...
def open_file(self, use_last_path=True) -> str:
    """
    Show an Open File dialog and return the filename

    :param use_last_path: Whether or not to start at the last folder opened
    :return: the selected filename
    """
    file_chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title="Open...", action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN)
    file_chooser.add_buttons(
        "Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, "Open", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.add_filter(self.csv_file_filter)
    if self.last_opened_path and use_last_path:
        file_chooser.set_current_folder(self.last_opened_path)
    response = file_chooser.run()
    filename = None
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = file_chooser.get_filename()
        self.last_opened_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
    file_chooser.destroy()
    return filename

def on_save_file(self, entry: Gtk.Entry) -> None:
    """Show a Save File dialog and set the filename to the given entry"""

    file_chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title="Save...", action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.SAVE)
    file_chooser.add_buttons(
        "Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, "Save", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.add_filter(self.csv_file_filter)
    response = file_chooser.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = file_chooser.get_filename()
        entry.set_text(filename)
    file_chooser.destroy()

def on_open_file(self, entry: Gtk.Entry) -> None:
    """Show an Open File dialog and set the filename to the given entry"""

    filename = self.open_file()
    if filename:
        entry.set_text(filename)
```

O botão que faz tudo estranho e que deveria apenas abrir um arquivo (mas que, como eu disse, removi o sinal `on_open_file` dele).

```xml
<object class="GtkButton">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Open</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
</object>
```

Os botões que são clicados magicamente:

```xml
<object class="GtkButton">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="GA_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>

<object class="GtkButton">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="OPS_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>
```

Cada botão acima está num arquivo `.glade` diferente e todos eles são carregados com o `Gtk.Builder`:

```py
builder: Gtk.Builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('./Views/main.glade')
builder.add_from_file('./Views/ga.glade')
builder.add_from_file('./Views/ops.glade')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    builder.connect_signals(Handler())
    window = builder.get_object('main_window')
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente o motivo, mas adicionar um ID para cada botão resolveu o problema. Então os botões se tornaram:

```xml
<object class="GtkButton" id="um_id_semantico_1">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Open</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
</object>
<object class="GtkButton" id="um_id_semantico_2">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="GA_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>

<object class="GtkButton" id="um_id_semantico_3">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="OPS_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>
```